# Reduce the number of additional Queries to 0 by overriding functions in the base model

Tags: symfony1

my basic database setup is:

```
User:...  
Info:  
  relations:  
    User: { foreignType:one }
```

When displaying information on the user it takes: 1 query to find info on the user, and 1 query to find additional info

I want to reduce this to one query that finds both, I assume I need to override a function from BaseUser.class.php, or something along those lines but I'm not really sure what to do.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using Doctrine, you need to override the `findOneBy***` methods in your `InfoTable` class to join data on retrieval

```
Class InfoTable extends Doctrine_Table {
   [...]
   public function findOneById($id) 
   {
        $q = $this->createQuery('i')
           ->leftJoin('i.User u')
           ->where('i.id = ?', $id);
        return $q->fetchOne();
    }
}
```

Doctrine will handle and hydrate the associated object, and save one query.

Comment: In the actions.class.php page it used the find() function to get the user object.  after changing this to use a findOneBy-- this solution worked very nicely

Comment: You could have override the find method too, as it is called by findOneBy*** methods, but this way is simpler.